# Could the proposal Scientific Imagination be kind of a duplicate of Earth Science

Tags: discussion

There is this new proposal that is quite hot on Area51 now. [**Scientific Imagination**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75912/scientific-imagination?referrer=IPIEcsN2huMFuP7v0aO_3g2). As it's description says, it is for the people who are interested in questions involving imaginary scenarios and scientific, educational, and fun answers for those questions.

I found some questions that might be on-topic here:

- [What would happen if we drilled a tunnel through the Earth along a chord in a great circle?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75912/scientific-imagination/76044#76044)
- [If the whole landmass of earth flattened (say, to 30 centimeters above sea level), will we have extra land?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75912/scientific-imagination/75917#75917)

However the difference of this from Stack Exchange science sites is, the [proposal is intended to be like what-if.xkcd.com](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17667/115322). So it does not only ask for answers, but also invites answerers to let loose their imagination.

Do any of you think this proposal could be a partial duplicate of Earth Science?

Answer (score 5):

There would certainly be a degree of overlap, on questions relating to earth sciences. However, if questions were asked here that were primarily about imagining fun & silly things, they would probably be closed as "primarily opinion-based" - so I think the actual overlap would be pretty small.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and of any science stack exchange. Part of being a scientist is imagining these types of senarios, and even famous things comes of it, for example, [The Drake Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drake_equation). I think it would be best suited of those questions were proposed in their respective science stack exchange.

Comment: But, there's a slight difference. While all SE science sites ask for answers, Scientific Imagination asks for answers+imagination. It is [intended to be like what-if.xkcd.com](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/17667/115322)

Comment: Oh I see. Interesting point, though I still think science SEs should facilitate the imagination as well, as long as they are carefully asked and responded to.